# Kendo Chart - show on column difference between current column's value and previous column's value

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, razor-pages

Is there possibility in Kendo Chart to display somehow the difference between columns, which are next to each other - you can see what I'm trying to achieve on the screen (blue pen means column's value, and red pen is my goal):

[image]

The Chart's code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model.Stats)
    .Name("columnChart")
    .Title("some title")
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(false)
    )
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
        .Background("transparent")
    )
    .Series(series => {
        series.Column(column => column.TotalAmount).Name("Total amount").Color("#007DC5");
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories(categories => categories.Date)
        .Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-90))
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis
        .Numeric()
        .Min(0)
        .Max(Model.GetMax)
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
    )
)
```

Comment: You probably could make it work. I would suspect it would involve a custom template for the label. I believe with a template, you could give your self access to the chart data where you could put some logic to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: Alternatively you could also just include a second chart dataset i.e. line chart using a different scale to show the difference so you would have 2 series on the chart rather than 1. That maybe clearer. I guess it just comes down to what your use case is.

Comment: You could play around with the Label Visual property, e.g.  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/arAGErEL

Comment: Or you could use labels and notes to show the 2 values separately: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aripAyAN

Comment: @ezanker thank you a lot, now I have to do this in Kendo MVC